# AWS RDS connection database error : com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I am trying to deploy my springboot application on an AWS linux instance however i keep getting the following error :

```
2018-04-24 18:15:27.777  INFO 24020 --- [ost-startStop-1] 

o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2018-04-24 18:15:28.771 ERROR 24020 --- [main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool: Unable to create initial connections of pool.

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]

... 

2018-04-24 16:58:57.522  WARN 23780 --- [main] o.s.b.a.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup : Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource

org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: 
Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

This is how i created my applications.properties file :

```
#database config
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://****-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/DevManagementDB
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=mypassword
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

The strange part is that i can connect to my RDS database from this springboot application when i am running the application on my local machine. As soon as i try to deploy the application to the linux instance on AWS it fails and i get the above errors.

Comment: Did you make sure security groups allow your EC2 instance? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html

Comment: yes i did make sure

Comment: Check the MySQL active connections by typing: 'show processlist' on MySQL console. And check the mysql max connection in mysql.ini. Which version of Springboot and MySQL you have?

Comment: MySQL 5.6.39 and springboot 1.5.9

Comment: how do i login ontop the mysql console?

Answer (score 1):

If your DB is an RDS instance, make sure the public IP address of the device accessing the DB is included in the RDS instance's Security Group. Also make sure the public IP address is included in Inbound channel of the appropriate VPC security group.

Answer (score -1):

I have also faced similar problem.
I have to update my mysql extra parameters from `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`

Stop mysql server `sudo systemctl stop mysql.service`

Need to update

`bind-address = 0.0.0.0 // replace 0.0.0.0 with required ip, 0.0.0.0 allows all ip`

Start mysql server `sudo systemctl start mysql.service`

also need to create a user who has access with that ip, add permission in mysql

```
mysql > CREATE USER 'user_name'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD'; // replace % with appropriate IP 

mysql > CREATE USER 'user_name'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD'; // replace % with appropriate IP

mysql > GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user_name'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION; // replace % with appropriate IP

mysql > FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Hope this will help someone